# Data handling Google Sheets and charts

Tags: google-sheets

I got a Google Form that are pushing data into my Google Spreadsheet. It's very simple and consist of 3 cols named:

```
A -> Date
B -> Type
C -> Data
```

There is three different types, which all have same data but different values (3 types data per day). I want to use these data in a bar chart, where X is the date represented per day basis, and the Y axis is the data value. But the series should be based on type, which in the end should lead to three bars per day.

This is probably fairly simple, but since I'm quiet new to G-Sheets, I have no clue of what to look for.

Dataset looks like the following example:

```
04-06-2016     house     140
04-06-2016     car       185049
04-06-2016     rental    14267
```

etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look at my [Bar Chart Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DgXmsnPpL3xsk2P7Zyw8a4fotcoApPXDa61b90Dgy0E/edit?usp=sharing).

The result looks like this:

[image]

Suppose, Data is stored in range A:C. I suggest select free cell (E1) and paste there the formula:

```
=QUERY({A:C},"select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col2 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col2")
```

It will convert Data, pivot it. Then select range wich you got with formula (E1:H8) and paste new chart, select bar type.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this query in another sheet, pulling data from the current sheet, for the query is in Sheet2 and the actual data is in Sheet1?? It is by adding Sheet1'!A:C instead of A:C :)

Comment: A side question, how do you add multiple series of data set to your chart? I splitted up the car, house and rental to have a sheet each, and if I add all these as range to the chart, it looks wierd :s

Comment: To add data from multiple sheets, set data like this: `Sheet!E1:G7, Sheet2!A1:A7`. Here's [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rR75wAdSCPDi3ALCu7fkEPc1WVO5yJphszUr3w5sJHc/edit?usp=sharing)